# Flood of error relates to alx module

Tags: linux, networking, kernel

My Linux box is flooded with the following error at a very high rate causing journald to go high CPU which causes CPU fan to get into high gear.  Strangely, the network still works.  Internet is not much help, only found a few irrelevant articles that's at least several kernels ago.  Any ideas on what's going on?

Apr 20 13:18:09 ###.#####.net kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0 eth0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting
Apr 20 13:18:09 ###.#####.net kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0 eth0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting
Apr 20 13:18:09 ###.#####.net kernel: alx 0000:08:00.0 eth0: fatal interrupt 0x4019607, resetting

Here is my box info:

cat /etc/os-release

NAME="openSUSE Leap"
VERSION="42.3"

uname -a

Linux ###.######.net 4.4.176-96-default #1 SMP Fri Mar 22 06:23:26 UTC 2019 (a0dd1b8) x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux

lspci | grep -i ethernet

08:00.0 Ethernet controller: Qualcomm Atheros Killer E220x Gigabit Ethernet Controller (rev 10)

modinfo alx

filename:       /lib/modules/4.4.176-96-default/kernel/drivers/net/ethernet/atheros/alx/alx.ko
license:        GPL
description:    Qualcomm Atheros(R) AR816x/AR817x PCI-E Ethernet Network Driver
author:         Qualcomm Corporation, 
author:         Johannes Berg 
srcversion:     385B6D0DA4526A8E53649AD
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A0sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d000010A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001090sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E0A1sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d0000E091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
alias:          pci:v00001969d00001091sv*sd*bc*sc*i*
depends:        mdio
retpoline:      Y
intree:         Y
vermagic:       4.4.176-96-default SMP mod_unload modversions

Comment: Your kernel is several kernels ago. Try updating.

Comment: Good suggestion.  I was hoping to maybe just update the driver.  But I will try updating the kernel if I don't hear any other suggestions.

Comment: AFAIK alx is in tree now, so updating the kernel _is_ updating the driver.

Comment: I have updated the kernel.  So far these messages are gone.  Thanks Michael.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=102171

It's still not fixed, so upgrading your kernel will not help currently.

Your only option to avoid this is to [disable the module](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/366609/how-do-i-disable-a-kernel-module-persistently).